# prove if one sample t test accept null hypothesis then one sample sign test must accept the null hypothesis

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

Can I say, for a small sample size, if one sample t-test accepts the null hypothesis then one sample sign test must accept the null hypothesis as well? And the mean given is equal to the median given. the null hypothesis is the mean(median) of sample equal to the mean(median) given.

Comment: Are you asking about comparing the significance of the $t$-test and the sign test for a sample size of $1$?  Can you motivate your interest in this if I've understood it correctly, or clear up a misunderstanding on my part?

Comment: not exactly, if n=1, then it is obvious hold, but how about n greater than 1? and I am not assuming that the mean of my data is following the normal distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No. The tests are not equivalent.**

All that is necessary is to find a normal
sample for which the t test rejects and the sign test does not,
or a normal sample for which the sign test rejects and the t test
does not. We consider right-sided alternatives: $H_0: \mu = 0$ vs
$H_a: \mu > 0.$ [Here $\mu$ denotes the mean or median.]

Among 100,000 randomly generated standard normal samples of size $n = 13$
the following program finds 2490 samples for which only the t test
rejects at the 5% level and 1985 samples for which only the sign test rejects
at the 5% (actually, 4.6%) level.

As expected, the t test rejects in very nearly 5% of the samples (5040).
In general, because of the discreteness of the binomial distribution,
a sign test cannot have exactly a 5% significance level. The sample size
$n = 13$ was chosen because $S \sim \mathsf{Binom}(13, 1/2)$ has $P(S \ge 10)
= 0.0461 \approx 0.05.$ Using this criterion, the sign test rejected (at the 4.6% level) in
4535 of the 100,000 samples tested.

```
m = 10^5;  n = 13;  pv.s = pv.t = numeric(m)
for (i in 1:m) {
  x = rnorm(n);  s = sum(x > 0)
  pv.t[i] = t.test(x, alt="g")$p.value
  pv.s[i] = sum(dbinom(s:13, 13, .5))  }
mean((pv.t < .05) & (pv.s > .05))      
## 0.0249                  # fraction of samples where t test rejects but not sign test
mean((pv.t > .05) * (pv.s < .05))
## 0.01985                 # fraction of samples where sign test rejects but not t 
mean(pv.t < .05)
## 0.0504                  # fraction of samples where t test rejects
mean(pv.s < .05)
## 0.04535                 # fraction of samples where sign test rejects
```

*Note:* This question illustrates the danger of trying one test first and then using the other
if the first does not reject. Then the true significance level of the
combination of both tests is about 7%, not 5%.

```
mean((pv.t < .05) | (pv.s < .05))
## 0.07025                 # fraction of samples where at least one test rejects
```

**Addendum** (in response to Comment):
Rounded to three places, here is as a sample `x` for which the t test rejects ($T = 2.362 > 1.782),$ but the sign test does not (number of positive elements $S = 9 < 10).$ However, finding just one such sample does not show the t test to be more powerful.

```
-0.988  0.393  2.117  1.841 -0.206  1.553  0.220  0.747 -0.197  0.373  0.734 -0.162  1.332
```

For a solid demonstration that the t test is more powerful than the sign test:
(a) Pick an alternative value $\mu_a > \mu_0$ and a sample size $n.$ (b) Use the non-central t distribution to find the probability of rejecting if the data are from a population centered at $\mu_a.$ [In R, the functions `pt` and `qt` include
the non-central t; use the third parameter.] (c) Use a simple binomial computation to 
show that the power of the sign test has smaller power (smaller probability
of rejecting if data are from a population centered at $\mu_a.)$

You could also get close to the exact power values with a simulation, but
doing the exact math would be best. Also, it is best to deal with normal data
because there may be some non-normal populations for which the sign test is more powerful
then the t test.

**Addendum** (on the power of the t test): As I mentioned in a Comment,
the exact computation of the power of the t test requires the noncentral
t distribution. We seek the power of the t test for testing $H_0: \mu = 0$
against $H_a: \mu = 1$ at the 5% level. With $n = 13$ observations from $\mathsf{Norm}(\mu_a = 1, \sigma = 1),$ the noncentrality parameter `ncp` is $\delta = \sqrt{n}(\mu_0-\mu_a)/\sigma = \sqrt{13}(1)/(1) = \sqrt{13} = 3.605551.$

To find the probability of rejection we want $P(T > c),$ where the $T$-statistic has a noncentral t distribution with 12 df, and noncentrality parameter $\delta$ as above, and
$c =  1.782288$ cuts 5% of the probability from the upper tail of the (regular) t distribution with 12 df. In R we find the power to be 0.960.

```
1 - pt(qt(.95, 12), 12, sqrt(13))
## 0.9597032
```

A simulation gives essentially the same result:

```
m = 10^6;  n = 13
pv.t = replicate(m, t.test(rnorm(n,1,1), alt="g")$p.value)
mean(pv.t <= .05) 
## 0.959472
```

Below is a 'power curve' showing power values for various alternatives $\mu_a.$
The power for $\mu_a = 1$ is emphasized with red dotted lines. The only point of the curve that is not a power value is at $(0, .05),$ where the rejection
probability is the significance level 5% of the test.

```
mu.a=seq(0, 1.5, by=.01); mu.0=0; sg = 1;  n = 13
ncp = sqrt(n)*(mu.a - mu.0)/sg
pwr = 1 - pt(qt(.95, n-1), n-1, ncp)

plot(mu.a, pwr, ylim=c(0,1), type="l", lwd=2, col="blue", 
    main="Power Curve of a One-Sided t Test")
  abline(v = 0, col="green2");  abline(h = 0, col="green2")
  abline(h = 1, col="green2");  abline(h = .05, col="purple")
  abline(v = 1.0, col="red", lty="dotted"); abline(h = .962, col="red", lty="dotted")
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, actually I am trying to find a sample for which the t-test accepts and the sign test does not. And this sample is not necessarily a normal sample. The main idea is to show that the t-test is more powerful than sign-test.

Comment: Addendum to my Answer now has such a sample, and also comments on power. Hope that helps.

Comment: New addendum on the power of the t test. I'll let you figure out the power of the sign test on your own. (Powers of t and sign test are not precisely comparable because the significance levels of the two tests are slightly different.) In a rough preliminary computation I got about 86% for power of the sign test against $\mu_a = 1,$ which _would_ be lower than for the t test.